# Date/Time Difference (Workhours/Workdays only)

Tags: calculated-column, date-time

I have a rather complicated (to me) Date/Time question.  I have a multi-step workflow, and am trying to build two calculated columns to track the elapsed time in business hours (M-F, 0800-1700) between two steps in the workflow. Here is where it gets tricky though, I also want to ensure I do not penalize the tasked user for any changes/modifications made by the requester. So, in this workflow, a supervisor creates a record... which is then processed by security. IF security rejects the record (maybe they need more info?) then the supervisor gets notified via the workflow. So, when they save the updates a field called "[Supervisor Modified Time (Security)]" gets date/time stamped. So, the first thing I do is check to see if that field is BLANK. If it is, I use the [Created] field as the start date/time. If the field is NOT blank, I use it as the start date/time. Now, the calculated field is working perfectly...and displays total Hours:Minutes, BUT, I am having a hard time getting it to NOT include time elapsed over the night and weekends.

Here is my calculated column so far... which works for straight time:

```
    =INT(
         ([Security Completed Time]
          -IF( ISBLANK( [Supervisor Modified Time (Security)])
               ,Created
               ,[Supervisor Modified Time (Security)])
             )*24
         )
         &":"
         &MINUTE([Security Completed Time]
                 -IF(ISBLANK([Supervisor Modified Time (Security)])
                     ,Created
                     ,[Supervisor Modified Time (Security)]
                    ) 
       )
```

If it helps, the basic calculation without field names and without the checks for ISBLANK looks like this:

```
    =INT((A-B)*24)&":"&MINUTE(A-B)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not solve this with a simple calculated field. I would recommend:

1. Create a column to store the difference of dates. It can be a numeric column.
2. Create a C # **event handler** to perform this calculation. After the calculation, update the value of the column. This can be done in the **onItemAdded** and **onItemUpdated** event.

Within the event handler you have all the power of C #. This will make it easier to perform a complex calculation.

Comment: I only have Site owner permissions and access to sharepoint designer 2016

Comment: That is a problem. You cannot use an event handler. I think you can try with javascript approach...